# Non local Initial conditions

Tags: semigroup-of-operators, integro-differential-equations

I am having a really hard time to try to understand this problem. what is non local initial conditions and how it work (or how we can use it) in practical applications like, in physics and engineering ?
Here is an example of system with nonlocal initial conditions:
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l c l}
\frac{dx(t)}{dt} + Ax(t) = f(t, x(t)), \ t\in I=(t_0, t_0 + a],\\  
x(t_0) + g(t_{1},..., t_p, x(.)) = x_0,&\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
with solutions when we are using semigroup theory maybe this :
$$x(t)=S(t)x(t_0) + \int_0^tS(t-s)(s, x(s))ds,$$

$S(t)$ is semigroup. For example, the use of this non-local conditions (here the function $g$) is said to enable additional time measurements
$_,  = 1, 2,\cdots, $ which is more accurate than measuring at $ = 0$ alone and provides more information about the system.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.